FastCGI cache always shows MISS
I setup FastCGI cache for my server running nginx and wordpress using this guide. It seems to miss the cache everytime. The specific server config is as below. What am I missing?
server {
    server_name <siteurl>;
    root /var/www/html/<siteteurl>;
    client_max_body_size 256M;

    index maintanence.html index.php index.html index.htm;

    ### Favicon
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ### Robots.txt
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don’t cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|/.*sitemap.*\.(xml|xsl)") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don’t use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 60m;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout updating invalid_header http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        fastcgi_hide_header Pragma;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        add_header Cache-Status $skip_cache;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<siteteurl>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<siteteurl>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = <siteteurl>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name <siteurl>;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

